# Can't isolate elements of string to convert and finish addition

Tags: python, string, integer, valueerror

I got an **example.txt** file, which contains:

```
4-1
9-3
```

as written format, string type. I need to open the file, and read lines, perform an operation and rewrite the file to:

```
4-1=3
9-3=6
```

But I constantly get an error when trying conversion, the problem I think is the `-` symbol, and it won't strip it, when I do `f.readlines` to get it as list there is `['4-1\n', '9-3\n']`. I managed to strip `\n` symbol.

My code so far:

```
with open('./izrazi.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lst = f.readlines()
    print(lst)
    first = lst[0]
    first = first.strip('\n')
    print(first)
    print(first.isdigit())
```

I tried to convert to a `set` ,and remove `-`, after that I converted it back to `list` and there are 2 elements only but after every run of code they are changing index position, and so I cant subtract.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Share your code for converting to set etc. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: has your question been answerd?

Answer (score 0):

`eval` performs a maths operation on the line

```
with open('./izrazi.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lst = f.readlines()
    [f.write(i.strip('\n') + '=' + str(eval(i)) + '\n') for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think.. something like this will do your job..

```
f = open('./izrazi.txt', 'r+')
text = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open('./izrazi.txt', 'w+')
for line in text:
    res=eval(line)
    out=line.strip('\n') + '=' + str(res) + '\n'
    f.write(out)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` will definitely do the trick, but there is a [school of thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) that using `eval()` is best avoided, so I will present an alternative using regular expressions.

Trying to use Python functions like `split()` becomes tricky quite quickly as you can only split on a single character. Regular expressions would allow you to find the components of the equation more easily. For example this regular expression:

```
r'(\d+\.?\d*)([\-+/*])(\d+\.?\d*)'
```

specifically looks for 3 groups (within parentheses):
`(\d+\.?\d*)` looks for a number, with or without decimal place
`([\-+/*])` looks for a mathematical symbol
so, together, they will find both numbers and any mathematical symbol you specify.

`matches[0]` contains the combination of all of the match groups, and matches[1], [2], [3] contain the first value, the operator, and the second value.

This enables you to perform the calculations without using `eval()`

```
import re

with open('./izrazi.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lst = f.readlines()
with open('./izrazi2.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for line in lst:
        matches = re.match(r'(\d+\.?\d*)([\-+/*])(\d+\.?\d*)', line)
        if matches:
            if matches[2] == "-":
                calc = float(matches[1]) - float(matches[3])
            if matches[2] == "+":
                calc = float(matches[1]) + float(matches[3])
            if matches[2] == "/":
                calc = float(matches[1]) / float(matches[3])
            if matches[2] == "*":
                calc = float(matches[1]) * float(matches[3])
            f.write(f"{matches[0]}={calc:g}\n")
```

With an input of:

```
4-2
9-3
3.142/22
34.2*91.44
9-3
3.142/22
34.2*91.4
```

This does give the desired output of:

```
4-2=2
9-3=6
3.142/22=0.142818
34.2*91.44=3127.25
9-3=6
3.142/22=0.142818
34.2*91.4=3125.88
```

As an aside, you can't use a `set` for operations such as `-` and `/` as they are not commutative. [A `set` object is an unordered collection of distinct, hashable objects](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset), so it simply not appropriate for use with mathematical terms.